# Infinite while loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

Can anyone see whats wrong with my while loop below? Basically I want to request a user to enter either "m" or "w", however, when I run it seems to enter an infinite loop despite the user entering "m" or "w".

```
While period <> "m" Or period <> "w"
    period = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the period (m/w): ", Title:="Period")
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Daniel, AND worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an infinite loop because if `period = "m"` then `period <> "w"`
and vice versa

Switching to the following is likely what you want.

```
While period <> "m" AND period <> "w"
    period = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the period (m/w): ", Title:="Period")
Wend
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `And` instead of `Or` pretty much any input will not be 'w' or 'm' including w and m.  (w is not equal to m so that conditional is still true and vice versa).